# We can guess the CTFT from the DTFT, but can we guess the Laplace transform from the Z-transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, z-transform

### **Notation:**

Say we have a continuous-time signal $x(t)$. We can take its Fourier transform and get 
$$x(t) \longleftrightarrow X(f)$$
We know that multiplying two signals in the time domain corresponds to convolving their frequency domain representations. We also know that a Dirac comb in the time domain is a Dirac comb in the frequency domain, so we can define $x_s(t)$ (the sampled version of $x(t)$):
$$x_s(t) \equiv x(t)\cdot\mathrm{comb}(t)$$
$$x_s(t) \longleftrightarrow X_s(f)=X(f)\star \mathrm{comb}(f)$$

Where I have used the $\star$ operator to denote convolution.

We're almost done setting up notation. We'll finish off with the Laplace- and Z-transforms:
$$x(t)\longleftrightarrow \mathcal{X}(s)$$
and, using the sifting property,
$$x_s(t)\longleftrightarrow \mathcal{X}_s(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\cdot\mathrm{comb}(t)\cdot e^{-st}\ dt=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-sn}$$

where I have hand-waved away the spacing between the impulses of the comb function.

Finally, we define $z\equiv e^{s}$ and get
$$x_s(t)\longleftrightarrow\mathcal{X}_z(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$

the Z-transform of $x[n]$.I've done away with the spacing between the impulses for the sake of simplicity.

### **The question:**

The effects of sampling in the time domain cause a "periodicization" in the frequency domain (i.e. the convolution with a comb function). If your sampling rate is [high enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), then you can completely recover $x(t)\longleftrightarrow X(f)$ from $X_s(f)$ by multiplying $X_s(f)$ with a rect function, in order to cancel out the "copies" of the spectrum produced in the convolution.

What I would like to know is if there is a strategy to at least *approximate* the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ knowing its Z-transform, $\mathcal{X}_z(z)$. I have tried to work it out by investigating the effects of sampling:

$$x(t)\cdot \mathrm{comb}(t) \longleftrightarrow \mathcal{X}(s)\star ??$$

In fact, the Laplace transform of $\mathrm{comb}(t)$ is already a bit strange:

$$\mathscr{L}\{\mathrm{comb}(t)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-k)\cdot e^{-st}\ dt $$
$$= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-sk}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-sk} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{sk}$$

(Note the negation of the exponent in the second summation on the right hand side). Problem is, I think this sum should diverge. It's not even clear what the Laplace transform of the comb function is, so I really have no idea what the convolution would produce in the s-domain, let alone how to undo it.

Anyone have any insight here?

Comment: To uniquely map a strip from the s-plane, $-\pi < \omega T \le \pi $,  to the z-plane, use the relation $z=e^{sT}$ where $T = \dfrac{1}{F_s}$ is the sampling period of the discrete system, IIRC.

Comment: You can also use Tustin's method to go from the z plane to the entire s plane, approximately: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform

Comment: But shouldn't this only undo the substitution $z \equiv e^{sT}$? It won't undo the effects of sampling, I don't think.

Comment: @Mahkoe just commenting here, about the divergence of the series of the Laplace transform, I believe I remember from signals courses that Laplace transform have a specific domain where are defined called ROC, which it is used to figure out even properties in the time domain. About the convolution, in my second answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f) question I believe I have found a way to avoid the convolutions, maybe it could be useful to your analysis (I hope so).

Comment: Hi Joako, you have certainly done a lot of work on this, it will take me some time to parse and understand all those details.