# There exists any real functions $f(t)$ on $[-1; 1]$ with $f(-1)\neq 0$ such $\lim_{w \to \infty} |w\cdot \int_{-1}^1 e^{-iwt}f(t)\,dt| = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

There exists any real functions $f(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ defined on $[-1; 1]$ (so $f(t)=0,\, |t|>1$), with at least $f(-1)\neq 0$ (hopefully also $f(1)\neq 0$), such it Fourier transform on $[-1; 1]$ is such that it will converges when multiplied by the first order polynomial, $\lim_{\omega \to \infty} |\,\omega\cdot \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-i\omega t}\,f(t)\,dt\,| = 0$ ???

Please, if possible, only continuous and differentiable functions "**within** the **open interval**" $(-1; 1)$, such the function and its Fourier transform could be simple and in "closed form". And with "functions" I mean that things like the "delta distribution" $\delta(t)$ is not an answer.

As example of what I am asking for, using $\Pi(t)$ as the standard unitary rectangular function [[1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_rectangular)]:

1. The function [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28%28t-1%2F4%29*pi%2F2%29*cos%28%28t-1%2F4%29*pi%2F2%29*unitbox%28t%2F2%29+from+t%3D-1.5+to+1.5) fulfill the requirements (so, it spectrum don't converges to zero when multiplied by $\omega$):
   $$f_1(t) = \sin\left(\left(t-\frac{1}{4}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\left(t-\frac{1}{4}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cdot\Pi\left(\frac{t}{2}\right),\, |t|\leq 1,\, (f_1(t)= 0,\,|t|> 1)$$
   Were its Fourier transform in $[-1; 1]$ can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_-1%5E1+e%5E%28-i*w*t%29*sin%28t*pi%2F2-pi%2F8%29*cos%28t*pi%2F2-pi%2F8%29*dt), and it's weighted spectrum $|\,\omega\cdot \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-i\omega t}\,f_1(t)\,dt\,|$ **did not converges to $0$** as it can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C%28%28-i+%CF%80+-+w%29+sin%28w%29%29%2F%28sqrt%282%29+%28%CF%80%5E2+-+w%5E2%29%29*w%7C+from+w%3D0+to+100).
2. But this function [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28t*pi%2F2%29*cos%28t*pi%2F2%29*unitbox%28t%2F2%29+from+t%3D-1.5+to+1.5) did not fulfill the requirements (this one actually have an spectrum that converges to zero when multiplied by $\omega$):
   $$f_2(t) = \sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)\cdot\Pi\left(\frac{t}{2}\right),\, |t|\leq 1,\, (f_2(t)= 0,\,|t|> 1)$$
   Were its Fourier transform in $[-1; 1]$ can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_-1%5E1+e%5E%28-i*w*t%29*sin%28t*pi%2F2%29*cos%28t*pi%2F2%29*dt), and it's weighted spectrum $|\,\omega\cdot \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-i\omega t}\,f_1(t)\,dt\,|$ **does converges to $0$** as it can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C-%28i+%CF%80+sin%28w%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%5E2+-+w%5E2%29*w%7C+from+w%3D0+to+1000).

In this example, I just added a translation in time, so I will expect to have a multiplication by just a phase on the frequencies, which absolute value is $1$ so nothing must be changing in the spectrum - This is actually wrong really, since I don't move the window defined by $\Pi(t/2)$, but seeing this just as a translation **within** the domain $[-1;\,1]$, is mysterious for me.

When doing the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f), I have tried **many different examples** (actually a few days doing trial-and-error), and I can't find any function whith $f(-1)\neq 0$ for which the mentioned weighted spectrum converges, when even the same "interior" functions were just time translation of the converging ones, so I left it as a conjecture.

I don't have any clue of why this is happening, so if you can explain it it will be awesome.

If they aren't exists in general, please explain why, or let a reference to the explanation.

Or conversely, if there are any proofs that the only way a real function $f(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ defined on $[-1; 1]$ will fulfill  $\lim_{\omega \to \infty} |\,\omega\cdot \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-i\omega t}\,f(t)\,dt\,| = 0$ is that $f(-1)=f(1)=0$, please let me know about it.

Also, Is the proof extendable to any finite domain $[a;\,b]$?? Or for unbounded domain $[0;\,\infty)$?? Or $(-\infty;\,\infty)$??

Beforehand, thanks you very much.

---

**Added Later**

I don't know why someone dislike this question, but I believe is interesting, since is related to something I am trying to prove in this other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f) (just at the end of the bounded functions examples). I am trying to figure out if is possible to a compacted support function $f(t)$ on $[t_0;\,t_F]$ with $f(t_0) \neq 0$, to have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |w\,F(i w)|\,dw<\infty$, with $F(iw)$ the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ on $[t_0;\,f_F]$.

Comment: You're asking for a continuous function $f$ with $f(-1)\ne0$ but $f(t)=0$ for all $t$ with $|t|>1$; that's obviously impossible, regardless of what you ask about the Fourier transform...

Comment: $\rightarrow\,$ David C. Ullrich: (don't know why I can´t tag you) You are totally right, that is why I am asking for differentiable and continuous only "insight" $(-1; 1)$ (I hope I have use the word "within" properly, I am not native English speaker). But to explain better the idea: $f_1(t) = \cos(t\pi/4)\,\sin(t\pi/4),\, |t|\leq 1$ is an example that fulfill my requirement, but $f_2(t) = \cos(t\pi/2)\,\sin(t\pi/2),\, |t|\leq 1$ is not.. I will added to the question. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I extended the question with the "why" i am asking this, hope it better explain my specific doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.

In other words, you are asking:
if $\tilde f(x) = f(x)\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}(x)$, is it possible that its Fourier transform $g=\mathcal F(\tilde{f})(x) = \widehat{\tilde{f}}(x)$ verifies $|x\,g(x)| \to 0$ when $|x|\to\infty$ and $f(-1)≠ 0$.

Notice that by the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), $g$ is an analytic function.

Notice that your problem is quite critical since if there is such a function, as $\tilde{f}(-1)≠ 0$, we see that $\tilde f$ is **discontinuous** and this is the reason why it is more difficult than when $f(-1)=f(1)=0$. In particular, the multiplication by $x$ cannot be replaced by a higher exponent: for any $n>1$, $|x^n\,g(x)|$ is unbounded.

- *Proof:* By contradiction, if $|x^n\,g(x)| ≤ C$ for any $n> 1$, then since $g$ is analytic, and so bounded by some constant $C_g$ on $[-1,1]$,
  $$
  \int_{\Bbb R} |g| ≤ \int_{-1}^1 |g| + \int_{-\infty}^1 |g| + \int_1^\infty |g|
  \\
  ≤ 2 \,C_g + 2\,C \int_1^\infty x^{-n}\,\mathrm d x < \infty
  $$
  so $g$ would be integrable, hence its Fourier transform $\tilde{f}$ would be continuous, which is false.

More generally you learn that $g$ is a smooth function that is too big at infinity to be integrable (but of course since $x\,g(x)$ converges to $0$ at infinity, it still verifies $|g(x)|≤C/(1+|x|)$)

---

**Edit:** I will prove the following:

**Theorem:** If the restriction of $f$ to $[-1,1]$ is in $C^2$ and $f(-1)≠0$, then it is not a solution to your problem.

**Remark:** $C^2$ is just here to simplify, one can more generally take $C^{1,\alpha}$ with $\alpha>0$ instead of $C^2$.

1- A simple case where one can prove that there is no such function. If $f(1)=f(-1)≠ 0$ and the restriction of $f$ to $[-1,1]$ is in $C^2$ (so twice differentiable with continuous second derivative) with $f'(1)=f'(-1)=0$.

- *Proof:* In this case, the function $\varphi = f - f(1)∈ C^2([-1,1])$ and verifies $\varphi(-1) = \varphi(1) = \varphi'(1) = \varphi'(-1) = 0$. Hence $\varphi ∈ C^1(\Bbb R)$. Since $\varphi ∈C^2([-1,1])$, $\varphi''$ is uniformly bounded on $(-1,1)$, and since $\varphi=0$ out of $[-1,1]$, $\varphi''$ is bounded out of $[-1,1]$. So $\varphi''$ is bounded everywhere (except in $-1$ and $1$ where it might be not defined, but that is not a problem): we deduce that $\varphi ∈ L^\infty$ and $\varphi''∈ L^\infty$. In particular,
  $$
  \|(1+|x|^2)\widehat{\varphi}(x)\|_{L^\infty} = \|\mathcal{F}(\varphi-\varphi'')\|_{L^\infty} ≤ \|\varphi-\varphi''\|_{L^1}
  $$
  so $|x| |\widehat{\varphi}| \underset{x\to\infty}{\to} 0$.
  But now for $f$ we have $\tilde f = f(1)\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]} + \varphi$ and so
  $$
  g = \mathcal{F}(\tilde f) = 2 \frac{\sin(x)}{x} + \widehat{\varphi}
  $$
  Therefore, $|x\,g(x)| = |2\,\sin(x) + x\,\widehat{\varphi}|$. Hence if $|x\,g(x)|\to 0$, then $|2\,\sin(x)| ≤ |x\,g(x)| + |x| |\widehat{\varphi}| \underset{x\to\infty}{\to}$ which is false.

2- The more general case without restrictions on the boundary values.

- *Proof:* Define $P(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$ the polynom such that $P(1)=f(1) = \alpha$, $P(-1)=f(-1) =\beta $, $P'(1)=f'(1)=\gamma$, $P'(-1)=f'(-1)=\delta$
  (it is not difficult to find this polynom, I get $a = \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{\gamma+\delta}{4}$, $b=\frac{3(\beta-\alpha)}{4}-\frac{\gamma+\delta}{4}$, $c=\frac{\gamma-\delta}{4}$, $d=\frac{\gamma+\delta}{4}+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{4}$). Then notice that
  $$
  \mathcal F(a\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}) = 2\,a\,\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
  \\
  \mathcal F(b\,x\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}) = 2\,b\,(\frac{\cos(x)}{x} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}) = 2\,b\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x} + O(x^{-2})
  \\
  \mathcal F(c\,x^2\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}) = -2\,c\,\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + O(x^{-2})
  \\
  \mathcal F(b\,x^3\,\mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}) = -2\,d\,\frac{\cos(x)}{x} + O(x^{-2})
  $$
  Then by the same reasoning as in (1-), $\varphi = f - P$ is a nice function such that $\widehat{\varphi} = O(x^{-2})$ and so
  $$
  x\,g(x) = 2\,(a-c)\,\sin(x) + 2\,(b-d) \,\cos(x) + O(x^{-2})
  $$
  which converges to $0$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$. And this implies in particular that $P(x) = (1+x)\,(1-x^2)$, so $f(1)=f(-1)=P(1)=P(-1) = 0$.

Comment: Really interesting answer, it gives me an insight about how to think about it. I am trying to figure out if is possible to a compacted support function $f(t)$ on $[t_0;\,t_F]$ with $f(t_0) \neq 0$, to have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |w\,F(i w)|\,dw<\infty$, with $F(iw)$ the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ on $[t_0;\,f_F]$.

Comment: I am trying to understand now the extended part: if I let $f(t) = \cos(t\pi/2),\,|t|\leq 1$, it will fulfill $f(1)=f(-1)=0$, and has $f'(1)=f'(-1)=0$ and $|w F(iw)|$ converges... It don´t fulfill the requirements to diverge of your example because $f(1)=f(-1)\neq 0$ doesn't happens? or because $f''(-1)\neq 0$ and $f''(1)\neq 0$ so is $C^2 \in (-1;\,1)$ but $f''(t)$ is not continuous at the boundaries?

Comment: No of course I was assuming that $f(1) ≠ 0$. I corrected and added the more general case where $f$ is $C^2$

Comment: Wow!!.. secondly, now trying to understand the general proof: What you have proved is that is impossible for any $C_c^2$ function?? Or for any function $C_c^n,\, n>2$?? Since a compacted supported function, to have continuous derivative of order $n$ it requires that, being $\partial t$ the boundaries, fulfill $\lim_{t \to \partial t} d^n f(t)/dt^n = 0$, I think you also proved the second one (it have to match a constant at the boundaries). But thinking in $n \to \infty$, since a class $C_c^\infty$ function can't be analytic, I don´t know if always I can make a polynomial for cases $n<\infty$

Comment: (continuing...), but a class $C_c^\infty$ function must start at $f(\partial t)=0$ so asking the main question is non-sense.

Comment: I do not get your concern. Warning about the fact that regularity is for the restriction of the function $f$ on the domain $[-1,1]$ (let call it $f_1$). Since the theorem works for any $f_1∈ C^2$, of course it works if in particular $f_1∈ C^\infty$ or any  $C^n$ with $n≥ 2$, or $f_1$ analytic. But since $f(-1)≠ 0$, of course the function $\tilde f = f\ \mathbb 1_{[-1,1]}$ defined on $\mathbb R$ is always discontinuous, so never $C^n$ for any $n≥0$.

Comment: I believe I have prove that this integral will diverge for every case where any of the values at the boundaries result to be different from zero, and also how to avoid this issue, in an additional answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f/4301842#4301842) question... hope you can see it and tell me if is something "new" for maths... beforehand thanks you very much.

Comment: I have incorporated now the general case into the question, were the only controversial scenario is the one you prove in your answer so I believe the question get closed now.

Comment: Please, do not change the question, it is better to add a new answer. But I think the reasoning is wrong anyway: there are functions $F$ such that $∫|w\,F (w)|\,\mathrm d w = \infty$ but $|w\,F(w)|\to 0$ ... for example $F(w) = 1/(w\sqrt{1+|w|})$

Comment: I have change it again as it was... thanks for noting my mistake.

Comment: I have corrected and uploaded as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized later the following: since any one-variable time-limited function could be described as:
$$f(t) = x(t)\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))$$
with $\theta(t)$ the unitary step function, given that $\theta'(t) = \delta(t)$ the Dirac's delta function, then:
$$ \begin{array}{r c l} \frac{df(t)}{dt} & = & \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))+x(t)\cdot (\delta(t-t_0)-\delta(t-t_F))\\
& = & \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))+x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)-x(t_F)\delta(t-t_F)
\end{array}$$
because of the sifting property of the delta function $x(t)\delta(t-a)=x(a)\delta(t-a)$.

Now, given the following definition of the Fourier Transform for a time-limited function $F(w) = \int_{t_0}^{t_F} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$ and its inverse as $f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(w)\,e^{iwt}\,dw$ (time-limited functions have unlimited bandwidth), assuming that $f(t)$ is that so it haves a Fourier Transform so it fulfill the Rieman-Lebesgue Lema ($|F(w)|\to 0$ when $|w| \to \infty$), and the use of the triangular inequality, then:
$$ \begin{array}{r c l}
\max\limits_t \left|\frac{df(t)}{dt} \right| & = & \max\limits_t \left| \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} iw F(w)\,e^{iwt}\,dw\right|\\
& \leq & \max\limits_t  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| i w F(w) \right|dw\\
& = & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|w F(w) \right|dw
\end{array}$$

But the lower bound of this integral will diverge at least for any $x(t_0)\neq 0$ or $x(t_F)\neq 0$ with $x(t_0)\neq x(t_F)$ because $\delta(t-a) = \infty$ and:
$$\max\limits_t \left|\frac{df(t)}{dt} \right| = \max\limits_t \left| \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))+x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)-x(t_F)\delta(t-t_F)\right|$$

Also noting that $\mathbb{F}\{df(t)/dt\} = iwF(w)$ could be also thought as:
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
\mathbb{F}\left\{ \frac{df(t)}{dt}\right\} & = & \mathbb{F}\left\{ \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))+x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)-x(t_F)\delta(t-t_F)\right\}\\
& = & \mathbb{F}\left\{ \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot (\theta(t-t_0)-\theta(t-t_F))\right\}+\mathbb{F}\left\{x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)\right\}-\mathbb{F}\left\{x(t_F)\delta(t-t_F)\right\}\\
& = & \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_F}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\,e^{-iwt}\,dt+ x(t_0)\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_F}\delta(t-t_0)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt-\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_F}x(t_F)\delta(t-t_F)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt\\
& = & iwX(w)+x(t_0)e^{-iwt_0}-x(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}
\end{array} $$
With this, the first inequality becomes:
$$ \begin{array}{r c l}
\max\limits_t \left|\frac{df(t)}{dt} \right| & = & \max\limits_t \left| \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(iw X(w)+x(t_0)e^{-iwt_0}-x(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}\right)\,e^{iwt}\,dw\right|\\
& \leq & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|w X(w)+ix(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}- ix(t_0)e^{-iwt_0} \right|dw
\end{array}$$

So now it can be seen that is equivalent:
$$\lim\limits_{w \to \infty} |wF(w)| = \lim\limits_{w \to \infty} |w X(w)+ix(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}- ix(t_0)e^{-iwt_0}| $$

So to have the possibility of having $\lim\limits_{w \to \infty} |wF(w)| =0$ the trigonometric functions have, or been zero so $x(t_0)=x(t_F)=0$, or happen that:
$$ w X(w)+ix(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}- ix(t_0)e^{-iwt_0} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow X(w) = \frac{i}{w}\cdot x(t_0)e^{-iwt_0}- \frac{i}{w}\cdot x(t_F)e^{-iwt_F} $$
which is not a general case.

The only controversial point could be $x(t_0)=x(t_F)\neq 0$ since I could have something weird of the form $(M - M)\cdot\infty$ and $x\delta(x)=0$, but this case have been shown to always be divergent on the already accepted answer gave by user @LL 3.14

Comment: There is a gap in the end of the reasoning. Saying that $|w \,X(w) + i\,x(t_F) \,e^{-i\,w\,t_F} - i\,x(t_0) \,e^{-i\,w\,t_0}|\to 0$  when $w$ is large does not a priori imply that $x(t_0)=x(t_F)=0$ or $w \,X(w) + i\,x(t_F) \,e^{-i\,w\,t_F} - i\,x(t_0) \,e^{-i\,w\,t_0} = 0$ ... there can a priori be lot more cases (i.e. converging to $0$ a being $0$ is very different!). My answer give that it will not work if $x$ is $C^2$ (even if $x(t_F)\neq x(t_0)$) and the same technique can get $C^1$ too, I think.

Comment: Maybe I express myself wrong,... what I was trying to explain is that if $(x(t_0)\neq 0)\vee(x(t_F)\neq0)$ then in the general case it will never been zero (except of the  particular case when $X(iw)$ is such that it cancel them out)... doesn't matter how $wX(iw)$ is in the long-run, if it don't cancel the trigonometric, it will never been zero since $\lim_{a \to \infty} \sin(a) = \text{undetermined}$, same for the cosine, and $e^{ix}\neq 0,\,\forall x$... that is what I think... but again, I am not mathematician, probably there is a lot of formalism I don´t understand about it...

Comment: I was expecting that you could use what I figure out to extend your answer to the general case, at least is why I upload my answer.

Comment: The problem is that it is "except in the cases where $X(w)$ is such that it cancels out **in the limit when $w\to\infty$**" which leaves much more possibilities.

Comment: mmm I don't know... Could you think of an example of cancellation in the limit different from $X(iw) = i/w\left(x(t_0)e^{-iwt_0}-x(t_F)e^{-iwt_F}\right)$??... PS: Did you check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4301842/909869) answer? Have you ever seen before the $\mathring{\mathbb{F}}\{\,\}$ transform?

Comment: I am trying to look for the conditions of convergence for improper integrals and I found [this](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.2307/1967286), where is said I think (I am bit lost here), that if the integrand has a infinite amount of min and max then the limits will diverge, but I don't really sure... maybe you can complete the answer with it.