# If $f(t)$ fulfill $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|dt < \infty$, Is then true $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2 dt < \infty$? If not, What else is needed?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, lp-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, integral-inequality

If $f(t)$ is a continuous **time-limited** function such that fulfills $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|dt < \infty$, Is then true that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2 dt < \infty$? If not, What else is needed?

I am working into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269062/are-there-tight-as-possible-upper-bounds-for-max-t-left-left-fracd-f) question looking for the conditions that will makes time-limited functions (so of unlimited bandwidth), to have a maximum rate of change $\max_t |df(t)/dt|$.

I think that imposing the restriction of $f(t)$ being of bounded total variation is too "strong" since it is contained in its definition $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(t)|dt < \infty \Rightarrow f'(t)\,\text{bounded}$, and also I have the problem of the discontinuity of the derivative in the domain boundaries $\partial t = \{t_0,\,t_F\}$ so the total variation has to be defined within the compact support as $\int_{t_0}^{t_F} |f'(t)|dt < \infty \Rightarrow f'(t)\,\text{bounded} \in (t_0,\,t_F)$.

Working in the question I found that **at least** any function $f(t)$ which fulfill that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|X(w)|dw < \infty$$ will have a bounded maximum slew rate $\max_t |df(t)/dt|$, whith: $$ X(w) = jwF(w) + e^{-iwt_F}f(t_F)-e^{-iwt_0}f(t_0)$$
and $F(w) = \int_{t_0}^{t_F} f(t)e^{-iwt}dt$ the Fourier Transform of time-limited function $f(t)$, and the other terms are to avoid the effects of the discontinuities at the boundaries $\partial t$ in the frequencies domain.

If the function $f(t)$ is of bounded energy
$$ E° = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2 dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_F} |f(t)|^2 dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(w)|^2 dw < \infty$$
through the Parseval's Theorem, I would like to relate them as "**since is squared-integrable, then its maximum slew rate is bounded**", but I don´t believe that directly $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |X(w)|^2dw < \infty \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty |X(w)|dw < \infty$, so I am looking for which is **the "least restricted additional condition" that will leads to a bounded maximum rate of change**.

Also, in [this](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.2307/1967286) paper I found that a integral  $\int_{a>0}^\infty f(t)dt < \infty$ if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (x^kf(x)) = A_k < \infty,\,k>1$, but I don't know if it can be related to what I want to do.

Comment: @podiki sorry but I don´t understand your comment... if I take $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |1/\sqrt{x}|dx \to \infty$ It don't fulfill the first requisite... There is something I am getting wrong?

Comment: It would be sufficient to add the condition $f\in L^\infty$ since then $$\int f^2 \leq \|f\|_{L^\infty} \int |f|$$

Comment: @LL3.14 If the functions is absolutely measurable, Does it implies its supreme is bounded ? $\int |f| < \infty \overset{\text{?}}{\Rightarrow} ||f||_\infty < \infty$?

Comment: No, since if it was the case the answer to your question would be yes ... the counterexample of user284331 is integrable but not bounded.

Comment: @LL3.14 but in the case of time-limited functions, I believe that if compact-supported and continuous $\Rightarrow$ bounded... isn't it? in that case if the function is integrable it will imply that is square-integrable, or I get lost?

Comment: Yes, right, continuous and compactly supported implies bounded :)

Comment: @LL3.14 Let me see if I follow your explanation: since is time-limited/compact supported and continuous, then is bounded ($||f||_\infty <\infty$? right?)... If I then adding that is integrable ($\int |f| dt < \infty$), then, it will be also square-integrable because $\int |f|^2 dt < ||f||_\infty\,\int |f| dt $, I am right?

Comment: @LL3.14 I trying to understand it because if what I ask is true, I don´t find why the counterexample of user284331 don't also fulfill them... is because is defined picewise?

Comment: Yes, you understood my explanation ... The example of user284331 is not a compactly supported function. You did not specify in the question that you wanted the function to be compactly supported (you just indicated it as a context/motivation for the question) so his answer just answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made the question some confusion was created because of describing the function as time-limited, when they are actually labeled as **finite-duration** functions.

As other have answer in the comments, $\int f^2 \leq \|f\|_\infty \, \int |f|$ so in general the answer is that not only absolute integrability is required, the function $f$ also must be bounded.

But what was tacitly implied in the question, noting my first paragraph here, is that the function $f(t)$ I am asking is a scalar one-variable function of finite-duration, so the function $f(t)$ is of compact-support in the time domain (I am not sure if this still stands if the function $f$ where of more than one variable, as example $f(x,t)$ will be limited only in the variable $t$ but in not in $x$, then probably the following explanation cannot holds), and since there is a theorem that states that **continuous and compact supported functions are bounded**, for the specific function $f(t)$ of the main question, it is already stated that fulfill $\|f(t)\|_\infty < \infty$, so being $f(t)$ absolute integrable was sufficient conditions in this case to be energy limited:

**scalar one-variable continuous finite-duration functions that are absolute integrable, are energy limited**.

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample:

Let $\{I_{n}\}$ be a disjoint sequence of intervals of length $\dfrac{3}{n^{3}}$.

We divide each $I_{n}$ into there parts. In the middle part we let $f(x)$ to be $n$, while in the left and right parts of $I_{n}$, $f(x)$ are the splines joining to the $x$-axis, and $f(x)$ are zero elsewhere, so this $f$ is continuous and nonnegative.

The integral $\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ can be controlled by $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\dfrac{3n}{n^{3}}=3\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$.

But then the integral $\displaystyle\int f(x)^{2}dx\geq\sum_{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}}=\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n}=\infty$.