# It is always true that $ \int\limits_{-t_0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt = 2\,\int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$??

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, signal-processing

It is always true that $ \int\limits_{-t_0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt = 2\,\int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$?? I think that is wrong but I can´t find my mistake.

First, let $f(t)$ and $F(w)$ been a symmetric-time-limited function and its symmetric-time-limited Fourier transform defined as:
$$f(t) = x(t)\cdot \left(\theta(t+t_0)-\theta(t-t_0) \right)$$ for a time $t_0 >0$, $\theta(t)$ the standard unitary step function, and $x(t)$ a arbitrary continuous and differentiable function (so, it could be even, odd, or whatever - not necessarily symmetric), so its Fourier transform is given by the following definition (if you choose other definition is going to be at least a difference of a constant, so feel free to use which is more comfortable for you):
$$F(w) = \int\limits_{-t_0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt $$
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(w)\,e^{iwt}\,dw $$
To avoiding any problem at its compact-support boundaries $\partial t =\{-t_0,\,t_0\}$ assume that $x(-t_0) = x(t_0) = 0$ (without lost of generality I think, since that problem is easy avoidable using the transform $\mathring{\mathbb{F}}\{\cdot\}$ I am using into this [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4301842/909869), so I am indistinguishable using a transform for which its Fourier spectra is "well behaved").

I am splitting the transform in two, so I will list step by step what I am doing, to see if someone can spot where I am making my mistake:
$$ F(w) = \int\limits_{-t_0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt = \int\limits_{-t_0}^{0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt+\int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$$
and let name the positive-time part as
$$G(w) = \int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$$
so now, working only in the negative-time part:
$$I(w) = \int\limits_{-t_0}^{0} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt$$ by using the following change of variable:
$$\begin{array}{c}
u \cong -t \Rightarrow du = -dt \\
t=0 \Rightarrow u=0 \\
t=-t_0 \Rightarrow u=t_0 \end{array}$$
I will have that
$$ I(w) = \int\limits_{t_0}^{0} f(-u)\,e^{-iw(-u)}\,(-du)= - \int\limits_{t_0}^{0} f(-u)\,e^{iwu}\,du = \int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(-u)\,e^{iwu}\,du$$
now, using another change of variable $w = - z$, I will have that
$$I(w) = I(-z) = \int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(-u)\,e^{-izu}\,du$$
which is the same form of the transform $G(w)$ but applied to $f(-t)$. Now, using the [time-scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Time_scaling) property of the Fourier transform:
$$\text{If}\,f(t) \overset{\mathbb{F}\{\cdot\}}{\rightarrow} F(w),\,\text{then}\,f(-t) \overset{\mathbb{F}\{\cdot\}}{\rightarrow} F(-w)$$
I will have that
$$I(w) = I(-z) = \int\limits_{0}^{t_0} f(-u)\,e^{-izu}\,du \overset{\text{time-scaling prop.}}{=} G(-z) = G(w)$$
So
$$F(w) = 2\,G(w)$$
As I am asking at the beginning, but I believe is wrong... Hope you can spot the mistake.

Comment: I don't think the time scaling property should hold for the one sided transform $G$.

Comment: It is false for $f(t)=1$.

Comment: Set $\omega = 0$ and some even function.

Comment: @copper.hat You mean “odd”, rather than “even”.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Yup, opposite day :-)

Comment: @copper.hat so it going to be true if $f(t)$ is real and even?? (so, $F(w)$ is real and even)

Comment: No, as @egreg was alluding to, if $f$ is even and $\omega=0$ then the integrals will be the same, so if you take $f$ odd then the left integral will be zero and the right integral will be whatever the $>0$ part of the integral is.